# my geometry program (Calculating area and volume of spheres, cylinders, and cones)

Tags: java

```
public class Geometry {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    input(0.0, 0.0);
    sphereVolume(0.0, 0.0);
    sphereSurface(0.0, 0.0);
    cylinderVolume(0.0, 0.0);
    cylinderSurface(0.0, 0.0);
    coneVolume(0.0, 0.0);
    coneSurface(0.0, 0.0);
    output(0.0, 0.0);
}
/**
 * @param radius
 * @param height
 */
public static void input(double radius, double height) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter radius r: ");
    radius = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter height h: ");
    height = sc.nextInt();
}

public static double sphereVolume(double radius, double height) {
    double volume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3.0);
    return volume;
}

public static double sphereSurface(double radius, double height) {
    double surface = 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2.0);
    return surface;
}

public static double cylinderVolume(double radius, double height) {
    double volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2.0) * height;
    return volume;
}

public static double cylinderSurface(double radius, double height) {
    double surface = 2 * Math.PI * radius * height + 2 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2.0);
    return surface;
}

public static double coneVolume(double radius, double height) {
    double volume = (1 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2.0) * height;
    return volume;
}

public static double coneSurface(double radius, double height) {
    double surface = Math.PI * radius * (radius + Math.pow(( Math.pow(radius, 2.0) + Math.pow(height, 2.0)), .5));
    return surface;
}

public static void output(double radius, double height) {
    System.out.printf("Volume of sphere: %f\n", sphereVolume(0.0, 0.0));
    System.out.printf("Surface area of Sphere: %f\n", sphereSurface(0.0, 0.0));
    System.out.printf("Volume of cylinder: %f\n", cylinderVolume(0.0, 0.0));
    System.out.printf("Surface area of cylinder: %f\n", cylinderSurface(0.0, 0.0));
    System.out.printf("Volume of cone: %f\n", coneVolume(0.0, 0.0));
    System.out.printf("Surface area of cone: %f\n", coneSurface(0.0, 0.0));
}
```

My problem is that my output results in 0.0 everytime, regardless of the input.  I'm sure it is probably something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can you please help me out?  Thanks a lot :)  I appreciate your time.

EDIT

So I am still getting 0.0 for my output even though I changed my code like this:

```
    public static void output(double radius, double height) {
    System.out.printf("Volume of sphere: %.13f\n", sphereVolume(radius, height));
    System.out.printf("Surface area of Sphere: %.13f\n", sphereSurface(radius, height));
    System.out.printf("Volume of cylinder: %.13f\n", cylinderVolume(radius, height));
    System.out.printf("Surface area of cylinder: %.13f\n", cylinderSurface(radius, height));
    System.out.printf("Volume of cone: %.13f\n", coneVolume(radius, height));
    System.out.printf("Surface area of cone: %.13f\n", coneSurface(radius, height));
}
```

When I am calling my functions in main(), looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    input(0.0, 0.0);
    sphereVolume(0.0, 0.0);
    sphereSurface(0.0, 0.0);
    cylinderVolume(0.0, 0.0);
    cylinderSurface(0.0, 0.0);
    coneVolume(0.0, 0.0);
    coneSurface(0.0, 0.0);
    output(0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Do I need to do something different here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dividing integers:

```
public static double coneVolume(double radius, double height) {
    double volume = (1 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2.0) * height;
    return volume;
}
```

Integer division rounds down in Java. Therefore, `1 / 3` is evaluating to 0.

Change it to:

```
double volume = (1. / 3.) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2.0) * height;
```

Here's the other occurrence:

```
double volume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3.0);
```

change to:

```
double volume = (4. / 3.) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3.0);
```

**EDIT :**

You're also calling all your functions with `0.0`. So of course the results will be zero.

```
System.out.printf("Volume of sphere: %f\n", sphereVolume(0.0, 0.0));
System.out.printf("Surface area of Sphere: %f\n", sphereSurface(0.0, 0.0));
System.out.printf("Volume of cylinder: %f\n", cylinderVolume(0.0, 0.0));
System.out.printf("Surface area of cylinder: %f\n", cylinderSurface(0.0, 0.0));
System.out.printf("Volume of cone: %f\n", coneVolume(0.0, 0.0));
System.out.printf("Surface area of cone: %f\n", coneSurface(0.0, 0.0));
```

**EDIT : Another Suggestion**

You probably don't need all those `Math.pow()` calls since they're all called with 2 or 3. I'd say it's probably more concise and readable (and faster?) to just do:

```
radius * radius + height * height
```

instead of

```
Math.pow(radius, 2.0) + Math.pow(height, 2.0)
```

**EDIT 2: More fixes:**

Change your `main` to this. And get rid of the `input` function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter radius r: ");
    double radius = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter height h: ");
    double height = sc.nextInt();

    output(radius, height);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I knew it was something simple.  EDIT -  Well I just changed that and I am still having the same error.

Comment: @eleven357: Then you're likely still doing int division, but somewhere else. Why not try to do a little debugging to find out ***where*** your error is occurring. A debugger or failing that, println statements should help.

Comment: You're also calling your functions with `0.0`. I just edited that in to my answer.

Comment: How do I call my functions with my input values for radius and height?

Comment: Just do `sphereVolume(radius, height)`. Same for the other calls. There's a number of places where you need to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out finally.  I appreciate all the help. :)

Comment: @eleven357: You also need to fix your `main` and `input` methods.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4545/discussion-between-eleven357-and-mysticial)

Comment: I just edited it in to my answer. Study it and you'll see why it should work. (I haven't tested it though.)

Comment: thanks dude!  I got it working.  I appreciate all the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Java guy but shouldn't you be storing the input into some sort of global variables?  Then using those variables as the arguments to your function calls instead of 0.0?  For instance, this code:

```
public static void output(double radius, double height) {
    System.out.printf("Volume of sphere: %f\n", sphereVolume(0.0, 0.0));
    System.out.printf("Surface area of Sphere: %f\n", sphereSurface(0.0, 0.0));
    System.out.printf("Volume of cylinder: %f\n", cylinderVolume(0.0, 0.0));
    System.out.printf("Surface area of cylinder: %f\n", cylinderSurface(0.0, 0.0));
    System.out.printf("Volume of cone: %f\n", coneVolume(0.0, 0.0));
    System.out.printf("Surface area of cone: %f\n", coneSurface(0.0, 0.0));
}
```

will just print out the results of those function calls with 0.0 as the inputs, not radius/height user input.

And, yes, the integer math isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

Are you typing your input by hand and relying on your `Scanner`? If so, that's your problem. The values from the `Scanner` are being assigned to your parameters in `input()`, and not actually being saved anywhere.

Your other methods are all being called with inputs of zero, for which outputs of `0.0` would actually be correct (although that doesn't mean you're bug-free).

Answer (score 0):

Create a class Cylinder; the class has attributes radius, and height. It has methods that calculate the surface area of a cylinder called surfaceArea  and a method to calculate the volume in addition to the needed set and get methods

Note : use the following formulas  for calculations :
    volume = (pi)r^2 * h where h is the height.
    surface area of a cylinder=2 * pi * radius * radius + 2* pi * radius * height
Cylinder
- height : float
- radius : float 
<>Cylinder(r:float,h :float)
+ volume() : float
+ surfaceArea(  ) : float
+ setRad ( r : float)
+ getRad( ) : float
+ setHeight(h : float)
+ getHeight() : float

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is old and was already answered. Typically, it is best not to resurrect stale threads unless your response contributes something significantly new or different over previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

when you using double, it should be sc.nextDouble().

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter radius r: ");
double radius = sc.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Enter height h: ");
double height = sc.nextDouble();
}
```